# Bootstrap Makes Text Look Like Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am utilizing this syntax, but for some reason it makes my text look like it is a button.  What I would like is for the text to just appear as text - black text with white background.  How can this syntax be altered so that the text does not have the same outlining as a button?

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
   <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Date One:</span>
      <input type="date" name="dateone" />
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
   <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Date Two:</span>
      <input type="date" name="datetwo" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
      <input type="submit" name="getthat" value="Show Me Info">
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

And here I also create bootstrap fiddle to show the visual:
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/35702/

Comment: Where is your issue?

Comment: The text Date One: and Date Two: has a gray background/outline so it favors the look of a button - not text.

Comment: Well, what you're doing is using [Bootstraps Add-ons feature](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/input-group/).  That's what it looks like.  If you don't want it to look like that, use something else?

Comment: @JamesThorpe - ah, I did not know that was the culprit.

Comment: There isn't a Date One or Date Two in your example link, can you update that to represent the issue?

Comment: @AndyHolmes - edited link.

Comment: Yeah James is right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<style>
.input-group-addon_1 {
  width: 1%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.input-group-addon_1 {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;

}
</style>
 <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
   <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon_1">Date One:</span>
      <input type="date" name="dateone" />
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
   <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon_1">Date Two:</span>
      <input type="date" name="datetwo" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
      <input type="submit" name="getthat" value="Show Me Info">
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This puts the text on top of the date - is it possible to have them both on one line?

Comment: i just make an uodate to the code....copy that and paste, i use a custom input-group-addon_1 that i created instead of input-group-addon

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  .input-group-addon 
  {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 0px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0px;
  }
```

add this class in your css file
OR
also use class for particular input-group

```
 .col-md-2  > .input-group > .input-group-addon 
  {
   background-color: #fff;
   border: 0px solid #ccc;
   border-radius: 0px;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change `input-group-addon` to `input-group`

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
   <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group">Date One:</span>
      <input type="date" name="dateone" />
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
   <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group">Date Two:</span>
      <input type="date" name="datetwo" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
      <input type="submit" name="getthat" value="Show Me Info">
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9txv3rfz/